# Ubuntu and SparkyLinux Gameover

Tags: dual-boot

Is it possible to dual-boot Ubuntu and SparkyLinux?
If yes - Can someone help me with info how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically every OS can be installed as dual-boot system. All you need to do is to leave some disk space unpartitioned when you install the first, so that the second can go there. If you install Ubuntu last, its GRUB boot loader should most likely detect the other OS and allow you to select which to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can follow the guide posted here to install your system:
[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Follow the guide with an empty disk first, and simply leave space at the end of your disk (i.e. after creating your / partition, or /home partition if you are separating them).
After the first OS is installed, you can then proceed to install the second one at the end of the disk.

If after installing the second system the first one does not show up in grub (or grub doesn't get used at all), you can either boot from Ubuntu's live disk and install and use boot-repair - the recommended settings should do the trick - or you can use a dedicated boot-repair disk found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).